# Flash AS3: Unable to view loaded swf after loading it inside of package

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, loader

Good morning friendly Flashers ;) So I've been trying since yesterday to just load a SWF file into my main movie. I've done this before just placing code inside a movieClip, but this time I'm working inside of Class files. I have my main class which calls a function inside of my sub class which contains the loader. My problem is that the swf will load (I can tell via traces) but I cannot see the loaded swf :(

Below is the code inside of my sub class

```
package src.howdinicurtain {

import flash.net.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;

public class HowdiniFrame extends MovieClip {   
    //public var splashLoader;
    public var introLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    public var introContainer:MovieClip;
    private var holdX:Number;
    private var holdY:Number;

    public function HowdiniFrame(url:String, loadX, loadY):void {
        holdX = loadX;
        holdY = loadY;

        this.addChild(introLoader);
        //this.addChild(introContainer);

        introLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));

        introLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfLoaded);
    }

    public function swfLoaded(e:Event):void {
        introLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
        introContainer = introLoader.content as MovieClip;
        //introContainer = MovieClip(introLoader.contentLoaderInfo.content);

        addChild(introContainer);

        introContainer.x = holdX;

        introContainer.y = holdY;

        trace("holdX = "+holdX);
        trace("holdY = "+holdY);

    } 

}
```

}

The code above will load the swf file, I can see the swf files trace statements from the start of the animation to the end, but I cannot actually see the swf file inside of the main swf.

**Traces:**

- *The SWF file is = intro.swf*
- *Intro Movie Starts :)*
- *contentLoaderInfo event removed*
- *Intro Movie Ends :(*

Here is the code in my main class that calls the sub class function that loads the movie:

```
var introPath:String = xmlOutput.intro;
trace("The SWF file is = "+introPath+"\r"+"\r");
hc = new HowdiniFrame(introPath, 0, 20);
```

I swear I throw my code into the first frame of a movieClip and it works fine, I see the animation in the loaded SWF play instantly, but when I have my code inside of Class files I cannot see my SWF at all :( thoughts? ideas? Thanks for any tips!

~ Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `hc`? Is that a MovieClip on the stage? What if you try:

```
hc.addChild(new HowdiniFrame(introPath, 0, 20));
```

or if hc is not a clip on the stage

```
hc = new HowdiniFrame(introPath, 0, 20);
addChild(hc);
```

Answer (score 3):

Always treat your children right. Don't forget to add them in everything you do or else you're a bad parent.

Comment: Haha, that should be a tagline on a Flash geek t-shirt at threadless or something....